# Java check if array[] item exists

Tags: java, arrays

I am downloading some data into a String array. Let's say `ImageLinks`. 
How do I check if a item in array exist?

I am trying

```
if(ImageLinks[5] != null){}
```

but it gives me `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. (Because there are really no 5 link in the array)

Comment: `if (ImageLinks.length > 5)` ??

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To prevent the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, you can use the following:

```
if(ImageLinks.length > 5 && ImageLinks[5] != null)
{
    // do something
}
```

As the statements in the `if` are checked from left to right, you won't reach the null check if the array doesn't have the correct size.

It's quite easy to generalise for any scenario.

Comment: What about an array where you set the indexes? Like in `a[0] = 20; a[5] = 30;`. If I check `if(a.length > 4 && a[4] != null)` it throws a null exception, doesn't?

Comment: @sdlins To be able to set index 5, the array has to have a length of at least 6 before you get to the if statement. At that point it'll check if the index exists and whatever it is null. There won't be any exception.

Comment: Yeah! Sorry, you are right! I tried by code it and it works fine. I was probably mixing different languages concepts. Thanx!

Answer (score 8):

Write a static function

```
public static boolean indexInBound(String[] data, int index){
    return data != null && index >= 0 && index < data.length;
}
```

Now, give it a call in your code

```
if(indexInBound(ImageLinks, 5) && ImageLinks[5] != null){
   //Your Code
}
```

Comment: This will not take care of the `null` case.

Comment: @Baz This is addressing the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, if we want to handle Null Condition we can anytime add one more catch block for NullPointerException

Comment: Just saying that OP wants to achieve both.

Comment: That is also right, there isn't any statement in the code throwing a NPE.

Comment: I got a few issues with this answer... 1) Exceptions should be used for _exceptional_ behavior; using exceptions to handle expected behavior, _such as in a `true` or `false` check_, is **_very_ bad**. 2) `is...Exists` is bad naming.

Comment: @XenoRo It was a very old post. Modified it to handle the case better. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Much better! Issues removed!

Answer (score 6):

Make sure array is of that length before doing lookup

```
if(ImageLinks.length > 5 && ImageLinks[5] != null){}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason its fails is the array has less than 6 elements.

Check first the array has correct number of elements, and then check the element exists in array.

```
 if (ImageLinks.length > 5 && ImageLinks[5] != null) {
     // do something
 }
```

Comment: Your answer is not correct. Refer to the "short-circuiting" logic on the following Java documentation page:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: if the first boolean statement is false and there is an && operator after it, there is no reason to continue evaluation as the entire statement must at that point be false regardless of whether or not the 2nd operand is true or false

Comment: Corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

yes there are less than 6 elements
ImageLinks[5] refers to 6th element as array index in java starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ImageLinks != null && Stream.of(ImageLinks).anyMatch(imageLink-> imageLink != null)) {
//An item in array exist
}
```